# Are there books that take you through a character's entire life?

Tags: plot

I'm wondering about developing a plot that spans the life of a character

Comment: Does Star Wars count? Parts one to six (available as books too) cover the complete live of Anakin Skywalker.

Comment: Sure, however they normal timeskip boring parts. There probably isn't a book that covers every single thing that happens to a character, unless they don't live long. Seriously, nobodys' life is that interesting.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr It should've been "life" instead of "live" ))) I agree anyway.. it's a good example!

Comment: It interests me... how are gonna do it? Will it be of any interest to anybody?

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, life and not live. Didn't have my share of coffee back than ;)

Comment: @AlexandervonWernher Mmm.. that sweet taste of coffee!

Comment: Heya, welcome to Writers.SE! Asking for existing books is off-topic here - and generally, the answer to "Has anybody ever done--" and "Can I write--" will both be a resounding "YES!". If you're *trying* to do something (like plot a life-spanning story arc) and running up against *a specific problem*, that would make a great question! But simply asking for generally-related examples is off-topic for us.

Answer (score 0):

There are writings that cover the complete life of the single person, like *North American Indian* novels by Liselotte Welskopf-Henrich, for instance, *Harry Potter* history by Joanne "Jo" Rowling probably should also count. Due many events they often span over multiple books.

There are also notable single books about the complete life of a non human character, like *Cowboy Horse* by by David R. Stoecklein or *White Fang* by Jack London.

Comment: You forgot about the film "The Truman show"